# How to properly create a single row table using IEntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How to properly limit a `DbSet<CustomEntity>` to hold a single row, using `IEntityTypeConfiguration<CustomEntity>`?

Currently I'm limiting the `GetAsync(int id)` method of this Entity's Repository to only return the first row and, on `AddAsync(CustomEntity newEntity)`, checking whenever new records are being added to make sure there's only one in the `DbSet<CustomEntity>`.

Here's the `IEntityTypeConfiguration<CustomEntity>` I'm using:

```
public class CustomEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CustomEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CustomEntity> builder)
    {
        // ID
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder.Property(e => e.Titulo).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(e => e.Dth).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.Resumo).HasMaxLength(2000);
        builder.Property(e => e.Pago);
        builder.Property(e => e.Publico);
        builder.Property(e => e.LinkFacebook).HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(e => e.LinkWebsite).HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(e => e.LinkYouTube).HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to achieve this through your repository. The EntityTypeConfiguration only specify the mappings between your CustomEntity and the database table.
You can apply QueryFilters to return only elements based on a specific criteria. But I would suggest to treat this business logic on your repository.
Here is the documentation of how to use them

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Guess I've already done what can be done regarding it being a single row on the Database (Limiting its repository's methods to only allow one insert and not requiring an ID to Get). I just hoped there was a way to set that via EF Core itself